# Any difference opening a TCP/IP port when running code as an application vs as a service?

Tags: c#, .net, tcp

I am creating a service that will open a listening TCP/IP port (to use a protocol known as DNP).

To debug the program, I've been using this bit of code in my Program.cs file:

```
static void Main()
{  
#if(!DEBUG)
    ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
    ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] 
    { 
        new ServerDNP() 
    };

    ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
#else

    ServerDNP ServerDNPProcess = new ServerDNP();
    ServerDNPProcess.MainProcess();
#endif
}
```

My OnStart looks like this:

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    this.workerThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(this.MainProcess));
    this.keepRunning = true;
    this.workerThread.Start();
}
```

In the actual process, I am output a lot of information to a log file and whether or not I run it as a DEBUG or Release the output to that file looks the same.

When I run it as DEBUG, the TCP/IP port opens up no problem and I can communicate with it from a remote machine. But when I run it as a service, I keep getting "no activity on the socket" errors on the remote machine.

Is there anything special I need to do for a service in order to get it to open a TCP/IP port? I've been searching and playing around for a while and cannot come up with anything.

Comment: Under which account is the service running?

Comment: I've got it set to the Local System Account

Comment: Shouldn't `#define` be `#if`?

Comment: You're right, Amy. I had trouble formatting it at first and accidentally replaced the #if with a #define. It wasn't a problem in the code, just here.

Comment: Okay, I figured that was the case.

Comment: I still expect your service is not starting.  Add some logging to the OnStart method, at the begin and end to see if it gets passed start of the workerthread. Does the eventlog reveal anything? Does it record the starting of the service (assuming AutoLog is true)?

Comment: The service is definitely starting. I removed a lot of the debugging/logging code in my code snippets to make it look less confusing. But I have some for "In OnStart" "In Main Process" (which happens just before it opens the port) and "Application Initialized" (which happens just after if it was "successful.") There are a bunch of other things getting logged and they look just like when I run it as debug. The only difference I can see is that I cannot see the port.

Comment: you could also run an elevated command prompt and run `netstat -a` to see if the port you expect is listed as listening

Comment: Weird. I see the port (0.0.0.0:20000) as LISTENING in both cases.

Comment: Can you `telnet` to the open port?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just an idiot.

I didn't realize that I needed to open the firewall for the process, and not just when I was running it as an application.